# If i use Redux in NextJS 13, will it be still server-side project?

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, react-redux, server-side-rendering

I want to use Redux in NextJS 13 project (app folder structure) . But for use it i need use provider, and provider will be in layout.jsx. But for use provider, i need use "use client"; annotation for make it client-side component. And my all pages using that layout too. So my whole project will be client-side or childrens will be still server-side ? If its makes all children client-side then whats point to use nextjs with redux ?

In other hand if i want to fetch datas from API and put it to redux, how can i do it ? For put it to redux i need "use client" annotation again. So i cant take data in server side. I'm actually so confused. Please help me for that questions. Thanks for help <3

Answer (score 1):

```js
"use client";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "../store/store";

const MyStoreProvider = ({ children }) => {
  return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>;
};

export default MyStoreProvider;
```

Use this custom provider with **use client** directive on top. Now wrap your layout with this custom provider

Answer (score 0):

By default if you add the `use client` directive in a component wrapper, in this case `layout.jsx`, all the children components will be client components.

However, you can still use React Server Components (servers-side as you say), and use these components at the `page.jsx` level, and their children could be either server components (default if parent is RSC) or client components if you use the `use client` directive.

About using redux with the `app` directory, it's possible. You could use your RSC to fetch data and pass that data to the redux `Provider` to store the data in your global store. Take a look to this [implementation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dRLjoT4r-jc) video from Jack Herrington. Just be aware that the redux store won't be available to your server components.